# unreleased final consonant sounds

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, consonants

At school I learned the unreleased final consonant sounds: b, d, d, k, p, t

My first question is, what  does *unreleased*  mean in this context?

My second question

> He played well and ran fast.

My teacher said the *st* in *fast* is ‘unreleased’. He said because it is joined. How do I know if the last letters in a word are joined and when they are unreleased?

How do I know if the word has an unreleased final consonant and how do I know what they are?

Comment: Why are you not asking your teacher all these things? You’re in class, you don’t understand something—just _ask your teacher_ straight away. That’s what they’re there for! If you do wish to ask questions here, please **try to find an answer yourself before asking**. Look up the meanings of words in dictionaries or encyclopaedias. This is not a homework site. For example, the very first Google result for “unreleased consonant” is [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release), which explains exactly what they are. What remains unclear after reading this?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have read in SE meta that SE is to be a place for all "answers," even if such answers exist elsewhere. I think that the site should not be so hostile towards anyone admitting to having a teacher.

Comment: @jlovegren Certainly—I wasn't saying the question doesn't deserve an answer because the answer can be found elsewhere, only that askers should try to find the information elsewhere and then let us know in their question why what they've found is not sufficient or does not answer their question adequately. And this is the fifth question Naser had asked within an hour in which he came here to ask for clarification on or an explanation to something his teacher said in class, which seems very strange to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it could just be one of the banned troll users. Who knows?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Why is naser not asking his teacher?  Perhaps his teacher is as unwelcoming in person as you are in cyberspace.

Answer (score 7):

The final consonant sounds in the question are called plosives and they have two phases when pronounced: first, a closure phase, where air pressure builds up behind a complete obstruction in the oral cavity (formed by the lips, by contact of the tongue tip with the alveolum, or by the tongue dorsum with the palate). For p, t and k, the vocal folds are not vibrating during formation of the closure. For b, d and g, they are (whence the distinction between voiced and voiceless stops). The closure itself has no or minimal sound, but it can be identified by disruption to the preceding vowel. Second is the release phase, when the closure is released. The sudden change in pressure in the oral cavity results in a loud sound. When a consonant is unreleased, the plosive at the end of a syllable has no release phase. In English, word-final plosives may be released or not.

Contrast with Vietnamese or Cantonese, where word-final plosives are *never* released, or French, where word-final plosives are *always* released.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I want to address the part of the question that deals with s. The st in 'fast' is a consonant cluster, which is simply a sequence of two or more consonants. As jlovegren explained, t is a plosive (also called a stop) and can be unreleased. s is not a plosive but a fricative. Fricatives are produced as air flows turbulently through a narrow channel between articulators. Because fricatives don't involve a stoppage of air, they also don't involve a release of any stoppage. In other words, there is no such thing as an unreleased fricative. When saying the word 'fast' in American English, speakers will normally articulate the s completely, whether or not they release the t.